# Which edition of visio supports UML?

Tags: uml, visio

I want to use visio to draw UML diagrams (not model). I have the option of choosing Visio 2007, 2010, 2013.
There are several editions of visio, **Which edition has UML built in?**

Comment: Why not take the last one ?  or google around ?  Apparently it's possible in all these versions: http://www.addintools.com/documents/visio/where-uml.html

Comment: 2013 will support definitely.

Comment: @Christophe, I have tried googling around, there is no clear answer anywhere, even Microsoft's site does not give a clear answer.

Comment: Since Visio is a drawing tool it can draw anything that is drawable, no matter which version. Some versions might come with stencils that resemble UML shapes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about version (2007/2010/2013) but about edition (Standard/Professional/Pro for Office 365). UML stencils are embedded in Professional and Pro for Office 365.

It is also possible to find stencils and import them into Standard but they aren't there natively and usually have some functionality limitation compared to those native ones.

For edition comparison for 2016 version see
[MS comparison for 2016 Visio editions](https://products.office.com/en-us/visio/microsoft-visio-2013-plans-and-pricing-compare-visio-options)

For 2007 I remember it was exactly the same for installed versions (sorry I'll not look for resources to confirm that) so apparently the Microsoft's approach here is constant.

Answer (score -1):

Here are quite pretty and free UML Stencils for any Version of Microsoft Visio:

http://www.softwarestencils.com/uml/

I tested it on Visio 2016. It works smoothly.

Comment: Please don't post product links as answers. Also, the question itself is 5 years old, and it's off-topic here - no need to add another answer to it. Just vote to close.